# Def, Void, Function?

Tags: language-agnostic, function

Recently, I've been learning different programming langages, and come across many different names to initalize a function construct.

For instance, ruby and python use the def keyword, and php and javascript use function, while VB uses void, etc.

My question is: What is the reasoning and differences between these different constructs and keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and all the many languages that copied from it don't use any keywords to declare a function -- you just to `<returned type> <function name>(<arguments)`.  `void` is just the way to say "no type at all", i.e. what we used to call a "subroutine" or "procedure" (a "function" that doesn't return any value).

`function`, as used in Javascript, is clearly a sharp and immediately obvious keyword, equally usable for both named and nameless functions.  IMHO, the best of the bunch.

I don't know what Guido was thinking when he chose `def` for named functions and `lambda` for unnamed ones (the Netherlands, where he was born and raised and where he was living at the time, has many wonderful beers, of course;-).  Ruby just adopted `def` from Python, maybe just because it's short (but it has no sensible meaning or interpretation...!).

Comment: `def` has no sensible meaning?  Isn't it short for "define"?

Comment: But, "define" _what_?  Why should "defining" indicate specifically named functions rather than unnamed ones, or classes, or dicts, or...?! And, why "define" rather than "default", "defer", "defect", "defenestrate", "defunct"...?  I love Python, and Guido's a friend, but `def` is just _the_ worst keyword in the language!-)

Comment: As pointed out, `void` is a return type and not a keyword to mark a function as `def` is. `def` seems to me to be borrowed from functional languages where even functions are first class types.

Comment: Functions are first-class in Python (`def`) almost as much as in Javascript (`function`) -- and SML (which uses `fun`, as does F#), O'Caml (`let`, like Scheme), Haskell (no keyword needed, e.g. `twice x = x + x` is how you define a function returning twice its argument). Scala does use `def`, but it's more recent than Python and Ruby; Lisp uses `defun`.